# WP_SITEURL vs WP_HOME link output

Tags: wp-config, options, configuration

When `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` are set to different values - for example *https://example.com/wordpress* and *https://example.com* - the output links are inconsistent.

Thus, a permalink output will be relative to `WP_HOME` like *https://example.com/my-url* but if you call for something like a thumbnail url it will return a link relative to `WP_SITEURL`, such as *https://example.com/wordpress/path/to/my-thumbnail.jpg*

I'm aware that this is the convenient behaviour, but for this one use case I'd rather have it output relative to `WP_HOME - as in *https://example.com/path/to/my-thumbnail.jpg* - the reason being that I'm migrating an archive and I chose to symlink new folders to old rather then change the urls for the whole thing.

It could of course be done by wrapping all calls into regex functions but I was wondering if there's a more elegant, general setting in order to achieve this.

Comment: Well you're wanting to use those two fields in a way they weren't designed to. It wouldn't be easy. Regex isn't a bad idea. If it was specifically uploads that concerned you (like your thumbnail example), could you modify the upload_path option? You define an UPLOADS constant that it is the path of where uploads are stored (and from whence they are fetched).

Comment: Would `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes` filter be useful in your case? Perhaps it could be used for modifying image urls. I got this idea from here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571779/how-to-display-post-thumbnail-with-modified-url-in-php

Comment: @the_hobbes, The trouble with UPLOADS is that [„This path can not be absolute. It is always relative to ABSPATH, therefore does not require a leading slash”](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) which puts it under /wordpress by default, while messing with ABSPATH itself would most likely have unwanted consequences.

Comment: @AnttiKoskinen, looks like a better place to put the regex, right? Still better then what I had thought!

Comment: I don't know if it would work, but since it's a path, could you not start with "../" ?

Comment: Nope, tried it, just spits the dots and slash like https://example.com/wordpress/../path/to/my-thumbnail.jpg

Comment: I guess that makes sense.

Comment: So what I did for now was to put this in my functions.php...

    `function website_image_rewrite_url( $rewrite ) {
    $rewrite = str_replace('https://example.com/wordpress', 'https://example.com', 
    $rewrite );
    return $rewrite;
    }
    add_filter('wp_get_attachment_url', 'website_image_rewrite_url');`

...waiting to see if there's a better solution out there